# Is is possible compute the max flow with max cost through an instance of maxflow-mincost?

Tags: graphs, optimization, network-flow, weighted-graphs

I have a flow network with gains. In practical terms, a gain is the opposite of a cost. So, I interested in finding the maximal gain of a network flow, what could be interpreted as finding a maximum flow at the maximum cost (or gain).

I'm planning to solve this problem by negating the arc costs and then to compute the maximum flow at the minimum cost.

So, my question concerns to prove or refute if this technique is valid; that is if the negated result of minimum cost after solving the max-flow/min-cost on the transformed network corresponds to the minimum cost. I would use a cancel cycle algorithm.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The mathematics doesn't care whether you call it a cost, a gain or an elephant. I don't know what you mean by "negating the arc costs" (literally replacing $x$ with $-x$?) but it seems very unlikely that what you're describing would work.

Comment: There is a well-known network flow algorithm for computing a max flow at the min cost. I have a situation where I have a finite gas flow to be distributed through several oil wells. Say us that the more gas passes through a well the more oil production you have. So I interpret this situation as to distribute the gas flow in a way that maximises the sum of oil production. My approach is to negate the production and then to compute the max flow at the minimum cost. The negated of the total cost would be the maximum production. All that I wish is validate this approach. Thanks for the interest

Comment: And of course, if that approach wouldn't work, why?

Comment: If all capacities are equal to one, and your source and destination have a single outgoing/ingoing edge, min-cost-max-flow is equivalent to shortest path. Max-cost-max-flow would be equivalent to longest path. This should concern you.

Comment: That is more or less the intuition under my reasoning.  I know the original network es acyclic and that finding a shortest path on -G (G with its weights negated) is equivalent to finding a longest one on G. But before starting to code, I would like to be sure that my reasoning is correct. Of course, on the residual network will appear lots and lots of negative cycles, but I think successive canceling would eventually leave the net without negative cycles and at this moment the flow assignations would produce the maximum

Comment: 1. I can't understand what you are asking, but is it covered by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem?  Can you re-phrase your question using standard terminology, e.g., the terminology listed there?  2. Since you have a candidate algorithm in mind and you want to know whether it is correct, what have you tried?  Have you tried proving it correct?  Have you tried searching for a counterexample?  Have you tried running it on a million random test cases to see if it gives the correct answer in every case?

Comment: Basically, is almost exactly the same terminology, with the subtle difference that, instead of associating a cost to an arc, I associate a gain and my goal is to maximize the sum of gains. So, as I tried (apologies) to explain, my idea is to negate the gains and to solve an instance of maxflow mincost problem on the resulting net (with the gains negated). I suppose that the negated total cost on this negated network would be the maximum gain given a maximum flow. Please let me know if you do not still understand and then I will edit my question. Thanks for you interest